# Прогноз стоимости YandexAPI не работает в моем примере

Tags: php, яндекс-такси

Отправляю запрос на прогноз стоимости Yandex такси, но в ответ получаю пустой 204-ый ответ сервера API.

См. Пример кода:

```
$url = 'https://taxi-routeinfo.taxi.yandex.net/taxi_info';

$options = array(
    'clid' => 'clid',
    'apikey' => 'key',
    'rll' => 'test adress~test adress'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?'.http_build_query($options));

$responce = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($responce);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по доке яндекса 204 значит что апи в вашем регионе недоступно, я бы проверил верные ли координаты в rll отправляете, прошу заметить - адрес должен быть в виде координат, а не адресом
https://yandex.ru/dev/taxi/doc/dg/concepts/trip-info.html

Comment: Да я в курсе что rll так задаётся. У нас уже одна система использует данную систему по моим предположениям. rll я задаю в формате 43.230385838927816,76.93361121975246~43.24996393218453,76.95132452808683

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/taxi/doc/dg/concepts/zone-info.html#zone-info

А этот запрос со своими координатами делали?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена. Не могу описать, но рабочим кодом можете ознакомиться тут

```
$clid = 'clid';
$apikey = 'API';
$class_str = 'express';

$fromlonlat = '43.230385838927816,76.93361121975246';
$tolonlat = '43.24996393218453,76.95132452808683';

$url = 'https://taxi-routeinfo.taxi.yandex.net/taxi_info';

$options = array(
    'clid' => 'https://taxi-routeinfo.taxi.yandex.net/taxi_info',
    'apikey' => API,
    'rll' => '{43.230385838927816},{76.93361121975246}~{43.24996393218453},{76.95132452808683}',
    'class_str' => 'express',
)

$ch = curl_init();
$curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?'.http_build_query($options));

$responce = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($responce);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Добавте, пожалуйста, основное по ссылке прямо в тело ответа.